# In oracle procedure how to fetch the PKId just added to be added as FK ID for next table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In an oracle procedure, I need to insert data in EmployeeHeader table and then later insert the PK id of this table as the FK id of EmployeeDetails table. How can we achieve this?

```
 INSERT INTO EmployeeHeader(
              HEADER_PK_ID
                      empNo

         )
         VALUES(
                    HEADER_PK_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
                    'SOMETHING'

              );

 INSERT INTO EmployeeDetails (
              DTLHEADER_PK_ID,
              HEADER_fK_ID
                      empname,
              age

         )
         VALUES(
                    DTLHEADER_PK_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
                    HEADER_PK_IDn, -- (THIS NEEDS TO BE FETCHED FROM EmployeeHeader)
                    21
              );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `RETURNING` clause of the INSERT statement:

```
DECLARE
  nHeader_pk_id  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO EmployeeHeader
    (HEADER_PK_ID, EMPNO)
  VALUES
    (HEADER_PK_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'SOMETHING')
  RETURNING HEADER_PK_ID INTO nHeader_pk_id;

  INSERT INTO EmployeeDetails
    (DTLHEADER_PK_ID, HEADER_FK_ID, EMPNAME, AGE)
  VALUES
    (DTLHEADER_PK_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, nHeader_pk_id, 'Somebody', 21);
END;
```

My personal preference is to use `ON INSERT` triggers to handle the population of primary key fields, in the following manner:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EMPLOYEEHEADER_BI
  BEFORE INSERT ON EMPLOYEEHEADER
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.HEADER_PK_ID IS NULL THEN
    :NEW.HEADER_PK_ID := HEADER_PK_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
  END IF;
END EMPLOYEEHEADER_BI;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EMPLOYEEDETAILS_BI
  BEFORE INSERT ON EMPLOYEEDETAILS
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.DTLHEADER_PK_ID IS NULL THEN
    :NEW.DTLHEADER_PK_ID := DTLHEADER_PK_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
  END IF;
END EMPLOYEEDETAILS_BI;
```

and the INSERT statements become:

```
DECLARE
  nHeader_pk_id     NUMBER;
  nDtlheader_pk_id  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO EmployeeHeader
    (EMPNO)  -- Note: PK field not mentioned - will be populated by trigger
  VALUES
    ('SOMETHING')
  RETURNING HEADER_PK_ID INTO nHeader_pk_id;

  INSERT INTO EmployeeDetails
    (HEADER_FK_ID, EMPNAME, AGE)  -- Note: PK field not mentioned - will be populated by trigger
  VALUES
    (nHeader_pk_id, 'Somebody', 21)
  RETURNING DTLHEADER_PK_ID INTO nDtlheader_pk_id;
END;
```

(I use the `IF pk_field IS NULL THEN` construct because I often need to copy data from production to development databases and wish to preserve any key values pulled from production to simplify debugging. If you don't have this requirement you can eliminated the `IS NULL` check and just assign the sequence's NEXTVAL directly to the column).

Done in this manner the application code doesn't need to know or care about which sequence is used to generate the primary key value for a particular table, and the primary key field is always going to end up populated.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `currval` in most cases:

```
select HEADER_PK_ID_SEQ.CURRVAL
from dual;
```

You might need to wrap the two inserts in a single transaction, if you want the values to be safe for concurrent inserts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RETURNING clause.

Here's an example:

```
create sequence test_seq1
  start with 1
  maxvalue 999
  minvalue 1
  nocycle
  cache 20
  noorder;

create sequence test_seq2
  start with 100
  maxvalue 999
  minvalue 1
  nocycle
  cache 20
  noorder;

create table test_tab_p (col1 number, col2 number);

create table test_tab_c (col1 number, col2 number, col3 number);

declare
  v_p_col2 number := 1;
  v_c_col3 number := 10;

  v_p_col1 number;
begin
  insert into test_tab_p (col1, col2)
  values (test_seq1.nextval, v_p_col2)
  returning col1 into v_p_col1;

  insert into test_tab_c (col1, col2, col3)
  values (test_seq2.nextval, v_p_col1, v_c_col3);

  commit;
end;
/

select * from test_tab_p;

      COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
         1          1

select * from test_tab_c;

      COL1       COL2       COL3
---------- ---------- ----------
       100          1         10
```

Comment: alternatively: `test_seq1.currval`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I think there may be scaling problems if more than one process accesses the sequence concurrently.

Comment: @BobJarvis: no there won't

Comment: @Boneist - yes, GordonLinoff just corrected my misapprehension about this. I've always used `RETURNING ... INTO...` so haven't dealt with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `currval`

```
INSERT INTO EmployeeHeader
  (header_pk_id, empNo)
VALUES
  (header_pk_id_seq.nextval, 'SOMETHING');

INSERT INTO EmployeeDetails 
  (dtlheader_pk_id, header_fk_id, empname, age)
VALUES
  (dtlheader_pk_id_seq.nextval, header_pk_id_seq.currval, 21);
```

`currval` is safe to use here. It always returns the last value obtained by `nextval` **for the current connection**. So even if other transactions (which means a different connection) calls `nextval` between those two statements, `currval` will still reflect the value of "this" `nextval` call.

[Quote from the manual:](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/schemaob.htm#CNCPT88879)

> Each user that references a sequence has access to his or her current sequence number, which is the last sequence generated in the session. A user can issue a statement to generate a new sequence number or use the current number last generated by the session. After a statement in a session generates a sequence number, it is available only to this session.

Answer (score 1):

The very efficient way will be just save the seq id value into a variable and then use it for the whole transaction. Below is the mentioned example. Let me know for any issues.

```
    DECLARE
      lv_pkid PLS_INTEGER:=SEQ.NEXTVAL;
    BEGIN
      INSERT
      INTO EmployeeHeader
        (
          HEADER_PK_ID,
          empNo
        )
        VALUES
        (
          lv_pkid,
          'SOMETHING'
        );
      INSERT
      INTO EmployeeDetails
        (
          DTLHEADER_PK_ID,
          HEADER_fK_ID,
          empname,
          age
        )
        VALUES
        (
          DTLHEADER_PK_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
          lv_pkid, -- (THIS NEEDS TO BE FETCHED FROM EmployeeHeader)
          21
        );
COMMIT;
    END;
```

Comment: There is no need for PL/SQL here - in fact PL/SQL will be _less_ efficient than a pure SQL solution

Comment: Yes it is true. Avoiding context switching :)